# Importing and looping through a PNG image to check for transparency

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, cimg

I would like to write CPP code that is able to take in a PNG file, scan through its pixels and identify where the transparent pixels are.

I tried doing this with CIMG, but it didn't work out as CIMG only supports the RGB channels.  Even after installing image magick, the 4th channel is not giving me the right values.

Anyone can suggest a library I could use?

Comment: Can you show some code that doesn't work? When you say *"4th channel is not giving me the right values"*, make sure you have the byte order correct - it may be ARGB or RGBA or even BGRA depending on your code.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084048/how-to-open-png-with-cimg-library-without-losing-alpha-channel